# How to pick independent variables in a large time series dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I merged 3 datasets all containing a yearly range from 2014 to 2022 and now I have 3 yearly coefficients: `Internet Penetration Rate`, `GDP`, and `GDP Growth`. How can I select the two independent variables (GDP and GDP Growth) from almost 30 columns? I'm using Jupyter Notebooks in VSCode.

This is the dataset:
[image: this is the dataset]

```py
X = df_merged.iloc[:, ].values # independent variables: GDP and GDP Growth %

y = df_merged.iloc[:, ].values # dependent variable: Internet Penetration Rate
```

What values do I put inside the square brackets?

Edit: I managed to define the independent variables with:

```py
gdp_col = [col for col in df_merged.columns if col.startswith("GDP ")][0]

gdp_growth_col = [col for col in df_merged.columns if col.startswith("GDP Growth ")][0]

X_columns = [gdp_col, gdp_growth_col]

X = df_merged.loc[:, X_columns]
```

But the problem is that when I print X I get the values of the GDP and GDP Growth from year 2014. How can I assign all the years?

Comment: Please, do not use images. You can provide a simple date example as text and thus provide a minimal reproductible example. Moreoever, what have you tried to but in the brackets ?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is independent of the size of dataset.

when you are looking for a location for multiple columns, this is how you do it:

```
X = df_merged.iloc[:, [df_merged.columns.get_loc(col) for col in ['GDP', 'GDP Growth %']]]
```

and for a single column:

```
y = df_merged.iloc[:, df_merged.columns.get_loc("Internet Penetration Rate")]
```

Comment: I get a KeyError on GDP, I think because each column has name + year.

Comment: Though it's a different error. It shouldn't be a problem. `get_loc` uses the name of the column and not the type to find out the exact column

Comment: Well, it's written as a string not a two type concatenation. The error means that there is no column simply called GDP. In my intuition I might need to iterate through all the years but I don't know how. If you can provide a better solution I'll be grateful.

Comment: Yes, for the DA part, you should be doing it. If the solution helped, please upvote and mark it as right